# Edit scores are not redirecting to the right site

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, achievements-dialog

While browsing stackoverflow.com, in my notifications I have a +2 score for an accepted edit on Server Fault:

[image: Accepted Edit notification]

This links to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112994/remote-desktop-connection-cannot-connect/1113061#1113061

But this is the wrong question—or at least, it's the right question number, but the wrong site.

It should be linking to: [Remote Desktop Connection cannot connect](https://serverfault.com/questions/1112994/remote-desktop-connection-cannot-connect/1113061#1113061)

I can see in the element that there isn't any hostname on the URL: `<a href="/questions/1112994/..."`>, so it will just redirect to that question number on the current site.

This happens on other sites I've tried, including Meta Stack Exchange.  Other kinds of achievements seem OK; only accepted edits are having this problem that I can see.

Comment: This was fixed today - see the answer to the duplicate.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks for letting me know!